# Validation Summary not showing the message box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validationsummary

I have an aspx page, which is opened in a separate window (redirected from master page). I have added some validations to that page. When I click on the submit button, leaving the fields blank the scenario should be like it should show up a message box (validation summary) but contrast to that the page is submitted. Validation Summary tag is as follows:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="MyValidation"
     runat="server"
     ShowMessageBox="true"
     ShowSummary="false"
     EnableClientScript="false"
     DisplayMode="BulletList"
     Visible="true"
     ValidationGroup="Group1"
     ForeColor="Red"
     Font-Size="9pt"/>
```

I have set the validationgroup with the same value for the text fields and the submit button as well. It is working in all other scenarios, but not working in the redirected pages.

I have installed FireBug addon to detect the issues through console. But no issues found.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @mikeTheLiar

Answer (score 0):

You should set either `ShowSummary` to `true` or `EnableClientScript="true"`. Since your code already has `ShowSummary="false"`,
replace

```
EnableClientScript="false"
```

with

```
EnableClientScript="true"
```

This will work when you need to display the message box.

Comment: Thanks! Done with that change too... But same issue. No message box is popping up.